# How to Group data from two arrays and get the count

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

if I have two arrays and region column has no same values
like

$data1=

```
Region             Type 
    ------            -----------
    EuropeWest         Operational
    EuropeWest         Operational
    EuropeWest         Operational
    EuropeNorth        Operational
    USCentral          Operational
    USCentral          Operational
    AsiaEast           Operational
    AsiaEast           Operational
    AsiaEast           Operational
```

$data2=

```
Region             Type
------             -----------
EuropeWest         MigrateSource
EuropeWest         MigrateSource
EuropeNorth        MigrateSource
USCentral          MigrateSource
USEast             MigrateSource
```

output should be as:

```
    Region             Operational      MigrateSource
    ------             -----------      ----------- 
    EuropeWest          4                2
    EuropeNorth         1                1
    USCentral           2                0
    AsiaEast            3                1
   Useast               0                1
```

Any help much appreciated?

I was able to group it but did'nt get any clue how to use foreach loop here:

```
$data1 | group -Property region | select name,@{n='Operationaclcount';e={$_.count}}
$data2 | group -Property region | select name,@{n='Migratesourcecountt';e={$_.count}}
```

Comment: Could you please show a [mcve] of what you have tried so far? Where are you running into problems? Starting points would be `Group-Object` and a `ForEach` loop

Comment: I was able to group it 
but didnt get any clue how to use foreach loop here 
$data1 | group -Property region | select name,@{n='Operationaclcount';e={$_.count}}


$data2 | group -Property region | select name,@{n='Migratesourcecountt';e={$_.count}}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine two arrays just use a plus. Something like this:

```
$data1 + $data2 | Group-Object region | % {
  New-Object psobject -property @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Operational = $_.Count
    MigrateSource = @($_.Group | Select Type -Unique).Count
  }
}
```

Comment: How do i get the migratesource count in the same object?

Comment: Amended answer for MigrateSource. Not sure how you get USCentral = 0 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two objects with a property `name`, if we combine these together we have a full list of names. With a `ForEach` loop, we'll loop over these names and use a `Where-Object` to filter each of the two objects you created for the count. We'll then create a new object with `[pscustomobject]`. Finally a quick test if a name is missing from a group that means the count was zero.

```
$OpCount = $data1 |
    Group-Object -Property region |
    Select-Object name,@{n='Operationalcount';e={$_.count}}
$MigCount = $data2 |
    Group-Object -Property region |
    Select-Object name,@{n='Migratesourcecount';e={$_.count}}
$CombinedNames = $OpCount.name + $MigCount.name
Foreach ($Name in $CombinedNames) {
    $entry = [pscustomobject]@{
        Operational = $OpCount |
            Where-Object {$_.name -eq $Name} |
            Select-Object -Expand Count
        MigrateSource = $MigCount |
            Where-Object {$_.name -eq $Name} |
            Select-Object -Expand Count
    }
    if ($entry.Operational -eq $null) { $entry.Operational = 0 }
    if ($entry.MigrateSource -eq $null) { $entry.MigrateSource = 0 }
    $entry
}
```